# Why does Ubuntu 22.04 TLS automatically restart when inactive?

Tags: 22.04, reboot

I just update my Ubuntu to the 22.04.3 LTS version and everything seems to work fine but when I don't touch anything (no activity) and the screen is about to get black, the laptop restart alone.

It happens all the time. When the screen turns black, the laptop reset automatically. But if I am active and work on it, nothing happen. It's a bit strange. It's like there is a config somewhere to restart the laptop when I am inactive.

Can someone give a hint on how to debug this or why it happens? All the questions that I found are about old versions or hardware issue (I have no hardware issue).

Here is my configuration if it can help

[image]

Comment: It sounds to me like the computer reboots when in fact it should suspend or hibernate. I would explore those options, maybe disable hibernation. I think this is where you should troubleshoot.

Comment: @ArturMeinild where I can control the "hibernate"? I have the "automatic suspend" turned off when plugged in

Comment: I'm not sure - I hope someone more familiar with Ubuntu Desktop can give a clue. 

Comment: @Rinzwind I already played with all the options there to disable the screen from turning black and to disable automatic suspend but it's not really a solution for me, I want to understand why it restarts and how to fix it.

Comment: @Rinzwind I don't want "nothing". That's more a workaround. I want it to behave normally by getting suspended/locked. Well, the default setting when you are inactive and you have to enter you password again to get back to work.